# Probability - A drunk man walking along the axis

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A drunken man walks along the X-axis, where the probability that he goes right is $p$ and the probability he goes left is $(1-p)$. 
What is the probability that the drunken man will be at $+1$ after the fifth step, if it is known that at after the 8th step he was at the origin $(0)$.

Well, it's easy to see that this is binomial distribution,
we want:

$P($ at +1 after 5th step $|$ at the origin after 8th step$)$

To get to +1 after 5th step, we calculate 3 step right, 2 steps left:

$A = {5\choose3}p^3(1-p)^2$

To get to the origin of the axis at the 8th step we need 4 left and 4 right:

$B = {8\choose4}p^4(1-p)^4$

I need:

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

I'm not sure I know how to get $P(A\cap B)$, should I calculate the probability that I get to origin from $+1$ in 3 steps? which is:

$C = {3\choose1}p^1(1-p)^2$

And then:

$P(A\cap B) = ({5\choose3}p^3(1-p)^2)({3\choose1}p^1(1-p)^2)$?

Can I get some help?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What does it mean "it is at the point $*$ after the $n$-th step"? Do you mean "at the $n$-th step"? Because "after the $n$-th step" it could be at any step after the $n$th step, ($n+1, n+2, \dots$ -th steps).

Comment: @Crostul, I mean after he finishes the Nth step

Comment: Did you read what I asked?

Comment: Look at my way, is it the right way? 
Is this the right calculation for $P(A\cap B)$ ?

Comment: @Crostul, I'm sorry but your all of your answers didn't help me and were irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry. Forget everything. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, we know the man was at the origin (0) at the 8th step and want to know the probability that he was at +1 at the 5th step, i.e. 3 steps earlier. There are only 8 scenarios where the man could end at the origin (0) after 3 steps:

1. -3, -2, -1, 0
2. -1, -2, -1, 0
3. -1, 0, -1, 0
4. -1, 0, +1, 0
5. +1, +2, +1, 0
6. +1, 0, -1, 0
7. +1, 0, +1, 0
8. +3, +2, +1, 0

Only in scenarios 5, 6 and 7 was the man at +1 at the 5th step. In each of these 3 scenarios the man must move twice to the left and once to the right, giving each a probability of $(1-p)^2p$. This means the total probability that the man was at +1 in the 5th step is $3(1-p)^2p$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the event in which the man is at $x = 1$ after the 5th step, and $B$ be the event in which the man is at the origin after 8 steps. Given that he is at $x=1$ after 5 steps, to get to the origin after 8 steps he needs to make 1 right step out of 3, so $$\mathbb{P}(B|A) = C(3,1) p(1-p)^2 = 3p(1-p)^2.$$ Using the identity $$\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \mathbb{P}(B|A)\frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$$ and the expressions for $\mathbb{P}(A)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B),$ we have $$\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \frac{3p(1-p)^2 \cdot C(5,3) p^3(1-p)^2}{C(8,4) p^4 (1-p)^4} = \frac{3 C(5,3)}{C(8,4)} = \frac{3}{7}.$$

The result is independent of $p$, this seems unintuitive to me. Have I gone wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The figure shown below are the three possible sets of steps to reach 0 from +1.

[image: Illustration of possibles steps from +1 to 0 in three steps]

The steps are as follows:

1. Right - Left - Left (steps in green)
2. Left - Left - Right (steps in blue)
3. Left - Right - Left (steps in red)

For each of the three above, 1 step is to the Right (probability = *p*) and 2 steps are to the Left (probability = 1 - *p*).  The probability of landing to zero from 5th to 8th step is

$P = 3 \times p(1 - p)^2$